# Ошибка в sql запросе UPDATE

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

в DAO пытаюсь выполнить такой запрос: `UPDATE PRODUCTS SET PRICE = ?, SET STOCK = ? WHERE SOURCE_ID = ?` используя `PreparedStatement()`, но получаю `java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "SET": syntax error)`.
Вот весь код:

```
PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE PRODUCTS SET PRICE = ?, SET STOCK = ? WHERE SOURCE_ID = ?");
        ps.setDouble(1, newPrice);
        ps.setString(1, String.valueOf(newStock));
        ps.setString(3, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

где промах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET` пишется 1 раз, дальше просто поля через запятую нужно указывать

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET PRICE = ?, STOCK = ? WHERE SOURCE_ID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Второй `SET` не нужен в запросе. Когда делаешь `SET` просто указывай параметры через запятую.